# Show TOP 4 rows into 4 columns in SQL SELECT Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to show values from one column in a SQL tabe into 4 columns according its top 4 values.

Example current table:

```
----------------------------------
ID | Name | Amount
1  | Test | 80
1  | Test2| 70
1  | Test3| 40
1  | Any  | 25
1  | Any1 | 15
1  | Any2 | 12
1  | Any3 | 5
2  | TS1  | 70
2  | TS2  | 55
2  | TS3  | 30
2  | TS4  | 19
2  | Any  | 11
--------------------------
```

Example expected SELECT Query result:

```
----------------------------------
ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4
1  | 80   | 70   | 40   | 25
2  | 70   | 55   | 30   | 19
----------------------------------
```

The issue here is to group the top 4 amount in 4 columns not considering names, just the numbers.

Is there some way to reach this result in table like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this pseudocode. Where data retrieves as per given ordering in sample input or storing position in database.

```
SELECT t.id
     , MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 1 THEN t.amount END) col1
     , MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 2 THEN t.amount END) col2
     , MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 3 THEN t.amount END) col3
     , MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 4 THEN t.amount END) col4
FROM (SELECT id
     , amount
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id) row_num
FROM test) t
WHERE t.row_num <= 4
GROUP BY t.id;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8d3b9a3da33f9177f2bb6957ef08e21b

Also you can use amount in ORDER BY clause in descending order as per expected result if needed. Try this pseudocode then.

```
SELECT t.id
         , MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 1 THEN t.amount END) col1
         , MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 2 THEN t.amount END) col2
         , MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 3 THEN t.amount END) col3
         , MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 4 THEN t.amount END) col4
    FROM (SELECT id
         , amount
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY amount DESC) row_num
    FROM test) t
    WHERE t.row_num <= 4
    GROUP BY t.id;
```

Comment: @ClaudionirQueiroz please check this.

Comment: Wouldn't it be good to add an 'ORDER BY amount' like .. (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY amount)? I know that in the sample data they all are already in order, but just in case.

Comment: I thought you need four value as on storing data in database. Yes if you want order by balance then which order ascending or decending.

Comment: I am not the one asking the question. Just pointing out that order could be different than shown in sample.

Comment: In MySQL it worked as a charm, but even addapting to SQL like this "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS row_num
FROM aux_aaa) AS t" it just return 1 row.

Comment: @ClaudionirQueiroz if you use only order by id at row_number() then it'll serialize data as ascending order. But if need id wise grouping then use PATITION BY ID and you can also use order by if needed. Row_number will reset every unique id.

Comment: @Reinis Verbelis was right. It worked better putting like him suggested in both case. MySql ans SQL, just changing this 'ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id) row_num' to 'ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY amount) row_num'!

Answer (score 0):

- FIRST STEP: Create Ranking (1 to 4) with `order by`  `DESC` amount as TOP 4 will be `highest` to `lowest`
- Second Step: USE `MAX()` on ranking to get all the rankings in one row rather than diagonally

```
WITH data as (

SELECT 
   ID,
   AMOUNT,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY AMOUNT DESC) RANKING

FROM [TABLE NAME]
)

SELECT 
ID,
  MAX(CASE WHEN RANKING = 1 THEN AMOUNT ELSE NULL END) COL_1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN RANKING = 2 THEN AMOUNT ELSE NULL END) COL_2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN RANKING = 3 THEN AMOUNT ELSE NULL END) COL_3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN RANKING = 4 THEN AMOUNT ELSE NULL END) COL_4
FROM data
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

### Alternatively you can use window functionality to achieve this result.

- Below is the query written in `postgresql`

```sql
select 
    id,col1,col2,col3,col4
from 
(
    SELECT 
        tbl.id
        ,tbl.amount AS col1 -- 1st
        ,LEAD(tbl.amount, 1) OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) as col2 --2nd
        ,LEAD(tbl.amount, 2) OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) as col3 --3rd
        ,LEAD(tbl.amount, 3) OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) as col4 --4th
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id order by amount desc) rn
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            id
            , amount
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id order by amount desc) rn
        FROM <TABLE_NAME>
    ) tbl
    WHERE 1=1 and tbl.rn <= 4 -- 4: variable
)tbl2
where 1=1 and tbl2.rn =1 -- 1: fixed
;
```

> **LEAD(column, n)** returns column's value at the row n rows aer the current row